# swapping bytes in float array

Tags: c++, endianness

I am currently working on a binary file format where the data is represented as an array of floats and the data is always supposed to be written with the little endian representation. So, currently I do something as follows:

```
float * swapped_array = new float[length_of_array];

for (int i = 0; i < length_of_array; ++i) {
    swapped_array[i] = swap_float(input_array[i]);
}
```

Here the swap_float swaps the four bytes of the floating point value. Now, I was wondering if there is a way to do this in a cross platform way without iterating using this for loop and making it more computationally efficient.

Comment: `new` sounds `c++`. why tag `c`?

Comment: Duplicate question (no research): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782725/converting-float-values-from-big-endian-to-little-endian

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/endian/doc/index.html

Comment: Also possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784082/how-to-do-serialization-of-float-numbers-on-network

Comment: It is not a duplicate as I want to do it on arrays rather than single floats...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me you can swap the bytes by using some pointer arithmetic:

```
byte mem;
byte* first = (byte*) floatpointer;
mem = *first;
*first = *(first+0x03);
*(first+0x03) = mem;
first++;
mem = *first;
*first = *(first+0x01);
*(first+0x01) = mem;
```

Comment: Should I not take the size of float on the given platform into account somehow... I think this assumes that the float is 4 bytes?

Comment: Well it is possible, will do a small rewrite.

Comment: Yeah, I will get it sorted. Thanks.